# How to replace function calls with array of #define in C

Tags: arrays, c

I am trying to compare different sorting algorithms in one loop. I have #defined function calls in a string array, but it doesn't call the functions as intended. What could be the problem?

function calls array:

```
const char sorts[][30] = {"bubbleSort(arr, size)", "quickSort(arr, 0, size-1)", "insertionSort(arr, size)",
                      "selectionSort(arr, size)", "mergeSort(arr, 0, size)"};
```

Calling functions using array:

```
for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_SORTS; ++i) {
    sorts[i];
}
```

I am sure there is a working way, thanks for help in advance.

Comment: You should look into *function pointers*.

Comment: There is no `#define` in the code you show, so nothing has been “#defined”.

Comment: In C, you cannot call functions via a string at run-time. Even if you could, `sorts[i]` is merely an expression for a string in the array. To call a function, you have to use the function call operator. (The function call operator is a set of parentheses with a possibly empty list of arguments inside them.)

Comment: I see the signatures and values passed are not the same in each case. Why not? As a first design step, why not standardize the API with which you invoke a particular sort, independently of the algorithm? i.e., it looks like you just want to take the pointer to the first element of the array and the number of elements in the array.  Not sure why quicksort is different, but it's easy to wrap it with something that calls it with size-1.  And not sure what the 0 argument is for, but again, provide a wrapper that injects the 0.  Then, function pointers to same-signature functions are the way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, declare a type to represent a sorting function (supposing your sorting functions accept arrays of integers):

```
typedef void (SORTING_FUNCTION)(int*, size_t);
```

Then, define an array of pointers to your sorting functions (here, hungarian notation for the C language would merely propose snake case, *bubble_sort*, while for `C++` it would be camel case *bubbleSort*, as you did):

```
SORTING_FUNCTION *sort[] = 
{ 
 bubbleSort,
 quick_sort_wrapper,
 insertionSort,
 selectionSort,
 mergeSort
};
```

and call it so:

```
sort[i](array, size);
```

taking `i` from 0 up to 4 in this case.

EDIT:  If some sorting function takes additional arguments, for example `quickSort`, then instead of calling `quickSort` directly, you define a wrapper function `quick_sort_wrapper` which will have a *SORTING_FUNCTION* signature and this function will call `quickSort`, passing it an additional argument, apart from `array` and `size`.

Comment: Additionally, `quickSort` presented in the question takes different arguments, so it needs a wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the best approach for a beginner, leaving yourself the best opportunity to get help from the compiler.

```
switch (i) {
  case 0:
    bubbleSort(arr, size);
    break;
  case 1:
    quickSort(arr, 0, size-1);
    break;
  case 2:
    insertionSort(arr, size);
    break;
  case 3:
    selectionSort(arr, size);
    break;
  case 4:
    mergeSort(arr, 0, size);
    break;
}
```